# Can I hide the inspect element option in a browser?

Tags: javascript, search-engine

I want to hide the "inspect element" option. I searched many ways to hide it, but didn't get any answers.

Is there any way to restrict it?

Comment: You cant, no, there surely already are questions about this on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Do you want users of the page not to do inspect element?

Comment: For security reasons I would hope that this isn't possible.

Comment: @DavidThomas you can make it harder, but in the end, that's all JS on the client side, which can easily be disabled.

Comment: Anything you don't want the user to be able to see or tamper with should be on the  server, not in JavaScript.

Comment: Could you clearify what you mean with 'inspect element of the search engine'? The only inspect element I am familiar with is the browser function.

Answer (score 0):

The closest you'll get is to block popular ways to access it (Javascript).

1. Use of F12 on the browser
2. Use of `Right`click
3. Use of other shortcuts involving Ctrl keys
4. Removing DOM when inspector is opened
5. Etectera..

It's the best you can do.
You could use shadow content if you want to hide your page. 
Or use PHP.

Comment: @Sirence I think answers on that would be quite alike. But yes. Once OP reads the answers he has to specify the problem once he notices he didn't get help.

Answer (score 0):

It is not really possible to completely block inspect element on your website.

But you can block some popular ways of accessing it. some of them include

**Use of F12 key on the browser:**
This can be blocked using javascript key event listener. Use the below script to do accomplish it.

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if(e.which === 123){

       return false;

    }

});
```

**2. Use of Right click**

You can block this using javascript or with just your html

```
<html oncontextmenu="return false">
```

or

```
$(document).bind("contextmenu",function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**3. Use of other shortcuts involving Ctrl keys**

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false" onkeydown="return false;" onmousedown="return false;">
Your body content
</body>
```